# wrapped parallel code way slower than non-wrapped

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am relatively new to Julia and I am having some issues when trying to parallelise. 
I have tried both `pmap` and `@parallel` approaches and I encounter the same issue. 
When I run something like:

```
addprocs(7)
A0=zeros(a_size, b_size, c_size)
A=SharedArray{Float64}(a_size,b_size,c_size)
toler=1e-3
maxit=1000
 while (metric1>toler) && (iter1<maxit)
`@inbounds` `@sync` `@parallel`  for i in 1:c_size
 A[:,:,i]=compute_A(fs,A0[:,:,i],i)
end
A_new=sdata(A)
metric1=maximum(abs.((A_new-A0)))
A0=copy(A_new)
iter1=iter1+1
println("$(iter1)  $(metric1)")
end
```

where the inputs of the function `compute_A` are:

- `fs` is `DataType` defined by me
- `A0` is an array
- `i` is the index I'm looping over (dimension c_size)

this seems to be working fine (even if instead of shared arrays and @parallel loop I use pmap)

However, when I use a wrap up function for this code, like:

```
wrap(fs::DataType,  toler::Float64, maxit::Int)
A0=zeros(a_size, b_size, c_size)
 A=SharedArray{Float64}(a_size,b_size,c_size)

  while (metric1>toler) && (iter1<maxit)
 `@inbounds` `@sync` `@parallel`  for i in 1:c_size
  A[:,:,i]=compute_A(fs,A0[:,:,i],i)
 end
 A_new=sdata(A)
 metric1=maximum(abs.((A_new-A0)))
 A0=copy(A_new)
 iter1=iter1+1
 println("$(iter1)  $(metric1)")
 end
end
```

Calling this `wrap(fs, 1e-3, 1000)` function runs WAY SLOWER than the other one (like 6 vs 600 seconds). 
It seems extremely weird and I don't understand what I am doing wrong, but there is definitely something I'm missing, so I was hoping I could get some help here.
I am using Julia v0.6.0.
Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (without ability to run code in question, this is really a guess) is `A0` is not a SharedArray, and when defined globally, it is effectively defined in all processors, so no communication is required for it during calculation (did you notice `A0` is a constant in your calculation?).

In the wrapped version it is defined locally in one process and communicated constantly to other processes. Hence the longer running times.

It is better to have maximal locality of data. If you define `A0` as a SharedArray of zeros using:

```
A0 = SharedArray{Float64,3}(a_size,b_size,c_size,
                            init = S -> S[Base.localindexes(S)] .= 0)
```

in both wrapped and unwrapped version. Furthermore, keeping each `[:,:,i]` slice on one processor would be ideal (by having `nworkers()` divide `c_size`).

NOTE: I'm not sure what kind of editing has been going on before putting the code in the question, but if `A0` is truly a constant zero tensor, there might be better ways to refactor the code. If `A0` is some other tensor, then try:

```
A0 = SharedArray(otherTensor)
```

**A relevant reference** is [SharedArray documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing#man-shared-arrays-1) which also details how to better split a SharedArray 3D tensor between processors, so slices remain inside a process for much better performance.

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz! But just a clarification because I am still a bit confused with parallel computing. so basically all the inputs that go in the function that will be computed in parallel have to be defined as shared arrays if arrays and `@everywhere' if constants? thanks for the help!